# how to remove/delete an 0..1 entity in entity framework 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4, entity

Hi I have an Events table and an InstallmentPlans table.  The relationship is 0..1 : an Event can have 0 or 1 Installment plans.  If I want to remove the existing InstallmentPlan for an event, how do I do this?  Setting it to null doesn't seem to work:

_event.InstallmentPlan = null;

Comment: Do you want to remove the association or delete the `InstallmentPlan` from the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use the object context to delete an entity from the database:

```
context.DeleteObject(_event.InstallmentPlan);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: yeah that's an option, but it's weird because if i set a breakpoint on that null statement, it would work, otherwise it wouldn't.  So I thought it should automatically remove that record if i set it to null.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to remove the association by key too:

> _event.InstallmentPlanKey = null;

This doesn't remove the object; to do that, you have to then also delete the entity as @Marek explains.

Comment: i'm just curious as to why it worked when I set a breakpoint.  it would actually set it to null and then remove the record from the database when committing.  But if i removed the breakpoint it didn't.  it seems it would fire some event that would keep you from setting it to null unless you stepped over it.  Weird.

Comment: Odd, because with or without breakpoints, it works for me.  I'm not sure why too.